# Get paid cash amount grouped by day

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table called `orders` this table contains all the information we need.

I'll just list the columns we need for the query:

- `purchase_price` (always contains the total amount paid for the order)
- `pay_method` ((int) when `1` it means the full `purchase_price` was paid for in cash, when `3` it means `purchase_price` was only paid partially in cash, other values mean other paying means so ignore them.)
- `cash_paid` (when the `pay_method` is `3` this column contains the amount of cash paid for the order, note that this is not the total price, it's just the part of `purchase_price` that was paid for in cash. When `pay_method` is NOT `3` this field's value is `0`
- `date` ((datetime)simply the date+time on which the order was placed)

The idea is pretty simple. we need to get the total amount of cash payed grouped by day.
But we found this a pretty hard task.

PS: I'm playing around with this problem in PHP using MySQL, so it's alright to use multiple queries and/or use some PHP script.

Comment: I'm an intern. So I'm doing this to finish my education, let's just say it feels like homework.

Comment: Oh, thank you. I gave up that website some time ago. I'll remove it :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [MySQL IF-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

If the pay_method is 1, take the purchase_price field. Else take the cash_paid field.

```
SELECT DATE(`date`), SUM(IF(pay_method=1,purchase_price,cash_paid)) 
FROM yourtable
/*WHERE pay_method IN (1,3) -- if you only want those */
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Answer (score 2):

In one query you could try like this:

```
select DATE(date), sum(case when pay_method = 1 then purchase_price else cash_paid end) from orders group by DATE(date)
```

btw. not sure if in mysql you can go with "case" inside sum function.

Comment: added missing "end" at the end of case statement

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `GROUP BY DAY(date)`

Comment: You are absolutely right, upvoted but not accepted because it only solves the grouping part of the question.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *, IF(`pay_method`=1,SUM(`cash_paid`),0) AS Cash_Paid FROM orders o
GROUP BY DATE(`date`)
```

Can you please try this. this will give you total cash paid... for partailly paid cash you can create another query and add them both....