# How to get count in this query?

Tags: mysql, sql, sqlite

I have one table with following columns:

```
ListID----           Status

1---------             YES

2---------             YES

3----------             NO
```

I want to write an SQL statement which will return count for each ListID column having Status as "YES".

How do I create this SQL statement, so that I get ListID 3 in it with Count as 0?

Please let me know.

Comment: Can you expound what the output should be like?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MySQL IF-function](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_if):

If the Status is YES, count the field. Else don't count it (0).

```
SELECT ListID, SUM(IF(Status="YES",1,0)) 
FROM yourtable
GROUP BY `ListID`
```

Checkout this previous answer: [Get paid cash amount grouped by day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4885035/get-paid-cash-amount-grouped-by-day/4885162#4885162)

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please let me know how this statement would look in SQLite?

Comment: 1. Use SQL92 CASE is better 2. use of having solve probkem wiout specific keywords.

Comment: what do you mean by date('ListID')....

i saw this looking very new to me .. but intresting

Answer (score 1):

TRY THIS

```
SELECT ListID, SUM(decode(Status,'YES',1,0))  
FROM yourtable 
GROUP BY ListID
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this very trick:

say YES is 1 and NO is 0
then just SUM(status) group by listId.

Answer (score 0):

For this is enough SQL92 statement:

```
SELECT ListId, COUNT(*)
  FROM table
 GROUP BY ListId, Status
HAVING Status = 'Yes'
```

Comment: stackoversflow write error when i try to post this block as code.

Answer (score 0):

```
select status, count(ListID) 
from tablename
group by status
```